# io6 allow interface orientation based on some condition

Tags: ios, orientation

I have a flag and user will set it from setting. If set to No only portrait orientation will be allowed. If flag is YES then both portrait as well as landscape will be allowed. 
in ios 5 and below

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation{
    //[image_signature setImage:[self resizeImage:image_signature.image]];
    if(flag == YES)
        return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    else
        return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

But in ios 6 and above above method deprecated. 
I was trying

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

But no success.
Please help me.

EDIT
I tried this.

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    NSLog(@"preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    NSLog(@"supportedInterfaceOrientations");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

But only supportedInterfaceOrientations is called only once. When I change orientation of simulater both methods not calling.

Comment: You didn't delete the -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate method did you?

Comment: No. shouldAutorotate returns YES.

Comment: Your new code shows you're using "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait" for the preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation method, that should be using UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait instead. Only the "supportedInterfaceOrientations" method should use the "mask" version. I thought you wanted both landscape and portrait if flag is YES ?

Comment: In appdelegate I had set rootView as navigation controller. Thats why it was not calling. I set viewController as rootViewController. It worked. But I need navigation controller as rootViewController.

Comment: See my updated answer with additional app delegate method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the view controller supports the specified orientation. 
(Deprecated in iOS 6.0. Override the supportedInterfaceOrientations and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation methods instead.)
```

(http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html)

So the two method you can use in newer versions are:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation

and

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

This method uses the following Bit **Masks**:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait

UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft

UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight

UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown

UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape

UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll

UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations

### Update:

OK, I'm not sure why it isn't working for you.

I've just created a demo app to replicate what you're trying to do:

(**use right click > copy image url and open in new browser tab to see bigger picture**)

[image: project setup]

When the orientation flag is NO, the button text shows "Landscape Denied", and rotating the device in simulator doesn't cause interface to rotate, as expected:

[image: Landscape Denied]

However after clicking on the button to allow landscape orientation, rotating the simulator device actually changes the orientation of the interface, as expected:

[image]

You don't have any other orientation delegate method in another root view controller overriding your current view controller's orientation delegate methods do you?

Also, I don't know if using Auto Layout interferes or not, I tend not to use it. In my View inside my XIB file, I selected the "View" object and then in the inspector, I **untick** "`Use Auto Layout`". My example project screenshot above is NOT using auto layout.

### Update 2:

Alright, I found this solution which worked with navigation controller as root view controller of window (**put this in your AppDelegate.m**):

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    NSUInteger orientations =UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

    if(self.window.rootViewController)
    {
        UIViewController *presentedViewController = [[(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController viewControllers] lastObject];
        orientations = [presentedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }
    return orientations;
}
```

in this Stackoverflow post:

[iOS 6 AutoRotate In UiNavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547134/ios-6-autorotate-in-uinavigationcontroller)

New screenshot with navigation controller:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In target I have allowed portrat, landscapleft and landscapright. and - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
} Still it rotates to landscape

Comment: Can you try using "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait"  (notice the word "mask" ) and see if it fixes it? i.e. -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations { return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait; }

Comment: And I put nslogs only supportedInterfaceOrientations is called. preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation is not called.

Comment: @Durgaprasad, please show your new code and describe the problem rather than simply "not working".

Comment: Thank you. It worked. About ios 5 will this methods called or shouldAutorotateToInterface will be called?

Comment: I am not sure. I don't think users with iOS 5 can install the update, I could very well be wrong :D. So I guess you can only target a base iOS version, either use iOS 5 or bite the bullet and use iOS 6.